# how to properly search special character on db(mysql) using php

Tags: php

There is is a cell on my db saved as `mx&#39;cp` instead of `mx'cp`.

So on my PHP search script I used `str_replace` like:

```
$str[$i] = "mx'cp";
$str[$i] = str_replace("'","&#39;",$str[$i]);
```

But when I echoed it

```
echo $str[$i];
result : mx'cp
not: mx&#39;
```

This cause an error on my db script as well cause its executed like this:

```
select * from user where name like '%mx'cp'
```

Instead of:

```
select * from user where name like '%mx&#39;cp'
```

Comment: Are you viewing thes results in a browser?  Try doing a View Source on the page.

Comment: Use a prepared statement instead of concatenating the value into your SQL and that `'` won't cause a problem.

Comment: ahh yes I am viewing it on browser using echo and die; but I think its also the same string with ' ( apostrophy) is executed on query since its resulting to error instead

Comment: @Don'tPanic hmm yeah I think thats a better approach.. thanks for giving me idea!